# Clean up moderator "merge questions" results page

Tags: feature-request

I just completed my first question merge as a moderator, and I noticed that the results page (which I unfortunately did not get a screenshot of) is uncharacteristically spartan; it's just a few lines of unstyled text. No "StackExchange" header, no menus, no footer, nothing; some raw text.

I think that page could benefit from a little styling. At least, the results should be in the same floating-style text box used for all other action results.

Comment: What did you merge, tags or users?

Comment: @MadScientist - I merged two questions. Question edited to clarify.

Comment: The blacklist page is plaintext as well.